# Chrome extension - page heading search - cant seach for h1

Tags: javascript, html, json

From this i need to make the h1 a defined variable

```
function display_h1 (results){
  h1 = results;
  document.querySelector("#id1").innerHTML =  h;
}

chrome.tabs.query({active: true}, function(tabs) {
    var tab = tabs[0];
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
        code: 'document.querySelector("h1").textContent'
    }, display_h1);
});
```

Comment: Sorry your question is a bit vague, can you clarify what is it that you are trying to achieve? are you are getting a `h1 is not defined` error in `display_h1`?

Comment: Sorry, fairly new to js. currently that displays the h1 of the active page in the extension popup. I want the h1 as a variable. im going to use it to search the web

Comment: No problem! are you looking to query a h1 inside the popup of your chrome extension? or an h1 inside the active tab?

Comment: hoping to get the h1 from the active tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so based on your comments, It looks like you are simply trying to query the dom (of the active tab) to get a reference to an `h1` tag with `id="id1"`.

For this you will probably need to use a `content script` that subscribes to a request from the `popup`.

You can try something like:

**On the content script.**

```
function getHeading (id){
  var h1El = document.getElementById(id);
  return h1El ? h1El.innerText : null;
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, callback) => {
    if (message.name === 'get-h1-content') {
        var text = getHeading(message.elId);
        // do what you need with the text.
    }
});
```

**On the popup.js**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    var queryInfo = {
        active: true,
        currentWindow: true
    };

    chrome.tabs.query(queryInfo, function (tabs) {
        var tab = tabs[0];

        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { name: 'get-h1-content', elId: "id1" }, null, null);
    }
});
```

So basically you send a request from `popup.js` to the `content script` running on the `active tab` so that the `content script` can **query the dom of the tab** and get the value of the h1.

Now, I guess it makes sense to highlight that the id you are using, `#id1` will obviously be specific to what you are using to test, and not something that will work on every page, so you might want to find another element in the dom to search by.